# Billing detail page doesn't work after I've changed the order of the Woocommerce navigation

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic, account

I've added the following function to change the order and translate my Woocommerce account navigation. It works perfectly, except for the `edit-address/billing` part:

```
function wpb_woo_my_account_order()
{
    $myorder = array(
        'dashboard' => __('Dashboard', 'woocommerce'),
        'wishlist' => __('Wishlist', 'woocommerce'),
        'edit-address/billing' => __('Billing details', 'woocommerce'),
        'edit-account' => __('Account details', 'woocommerce'),
        'customer-logout' => __('Logout', 'woocommerce'),
    );
    return $myorder;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'wpb_woo_my_account_order');
```

When I go to my account and click on Billing details in the navigation, I get a page not found URL error. The URL is `/edit-address%2Fbilling/` instead of `/edit-address/billing/` The issue is that the `/` is replaced with `%2F`

Comment: Looks like it's probably expecting a slug and as such is sanitizing it for use in a URL, instead of being a path like you're expecting

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the latest version of WPML that causes this problem. WPML has a quick fix for this:
https://wpml.org/errata/endpoints-containing-slashes-are-incorrectly-encoded/